# Velocity addition rule in special relativity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, velocity

I just worked out a problem showing peculiarities of the velocity addition rule in special relativity. This was the statement for the problem:

> "Nefarious thieves flee the scene of their bank robbery in a supercharged car traveling at $3/4 c$.  Hot on their tail is a police car, which pursues them at $3/5 c$.  Realizing that they will never catch up, one of the police officers fires his gun out the window at the thieves’ tires.  The bullet’s velocity (relative to the gun) is $1/5c$."

Working out the problem you get the result that, from the point of view of a stationary observer, the bullet will never reach the thieves' vehicle. My question is:

How is this resolved in the police officer's frame of reference? Will he simply see the bullet moving at a slower speed than $1/5c$ relative to himself?

Comment: I take it you are assuming that the police see the robber moving at 0.15c relative to them. Is that a fair and correct thing to assume?

Comment: Aha! That seemed to be precisely the issue! Thank you! Sometimes it is just necessary to have someone tell me how I was making a silly assumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So by the rule of velocity addition,

Velocity of thieves relative to lab frame = $\frac{3}{4} c = u_1$

Velocity of lab frame relative to police = $-\frac{3}{5} c = u_2$

Thus velocity of thieves relative to police = $\frac{u_1+u_2}{1+\frac{u_1u_2}{c^2}} = \frac{3}{11} c$

Since velocity of bullet relative to police = $\frac{1}{5} c $ and $\frac{3}{11} c > \frac{1}{5} c$

The thieves are faster than the bullet and the bullet can never catch them in police's frame(or in any other frame if you do similar calculations.)

Relativity works :)

Comment: Thank you! I realised that I was making the assumption that the velocity of the thieves in the police frame was Galilean whilst doing the calculations for the velocity of the bullet in proper Einsteinian; a silly mistake.

Comment: Glad it helped :) Silly mistakes do happen sometimes haha

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use Lorentz Boost parameters (aka rapidity) which are additive.  An observer sitting still on the earth sees:
$$
\lambda_{Robbers}=tanh^{-1}({3 \over 4})=0.972955
$$
$$
\lambda_{Police}=tanh^{-1}({3 \over 5})=0.693147
$$
$$
\lambda_{Bullet}=tanh^{-1}({3 \over 5})+tanh^{-1}({1 \over 5})=0.895880
$$
Notice that  $\lambda_{Bullet} < \lambda_{Robbers}$ so the bullet never catches up to the robbers. An observer riding in the robbers' car sees:
$$
\lambda_{BulletSeenByRobbers}=\lambda_{Bullet}-\lambda_{Robbers}=-0.077075
$$
$$
v_{BulletSeenByRobbers}=tanh(\lambda_{BulletSeenByRobbers})=-0.076923c
$$
which is the velocity the robbers see the bullet moving away at.

Comment: I am not familiar with rapidity, nor am I sure that it will be covered in the course that I'm currently taking, but I shall certainly look into it now! Thank you!

Comment: The Lorentz Boost parameters are the numbers in the exponent for the boost transformation $e^{\lambda K}$ where K is the boost "generator" (an operator or matrix).  The $\lambda$ are useful. For example, ${v \over c}=tanh(\lambda)$,  $\gamma =cosh(\lambda)$, and $\beta \gamma = sinh(\lambda)$.  Have fun.

Comment: The boost parameters also make remembering and writing the Lorentz transformation matrix easier: $$ \begin{bmatrix}  t' \\ x' \\ y' \\ z' \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} cosh(\lambda) & sinh(\lambda) & 0 & 0\\ sinh(\lambda) & cosh(\lambda) & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} t \\ x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix}$$  It is like a rotation matrix except with hyperbolic functions and it's symmetric rather than antisymmetric.